# Transaction spans multiple EJB Instances

Tags: hibernate, ejb

I have spent last two days to figure out a Hibernate Transaction Problem...

I am using Websphere 5.1 (J2EE 1.4) and have two EJBs deployed which are using Hibernate as ORM.

Here is the config we are using [Transaction_demarcation_with_EJBCMT](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions#Transaction_demarcation_with_EJBCMT)

The logic is simply like that :

```
EJB1.business_logic()
    context.lookup(EJB2)
    for x times
       EJB2.save_to_Hibernate()
    end
end
```

The problem is that I want to have a seperated Transaction where each call to EJB2.save_to_Hibernate() is committed into DB. I expect to mark EJB2.save_to_Hibernate() as RequiresNew will do the job but never worked.

I have tried so many options. It always commits when EJB1.business_logic() method exits.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It works fine on Glassfish 3.1 (but it's Java EE 6, so completely different world). EJB 2 is a different EJB than EJB 1, so there is no possibility that you're invoking a local call instead of EJB business call?

Comment: Have you tried to commit the transaction explicitly for `save_to_Hibernate()` using BMT. In case of CMT, you can try to flush the changes.